# Ubuntu Server 14.04 LAMP change the directory of php

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I have ubuntu server 14.04 installed and the problem im facing is that whenever I set

```
require_once '/connection.php';
```

I get the problem saying no such file or directory. I can fix this by using

```
require_once '/var/www/html/connection.php';
```

or with

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once (__ROOT__ . '/connection.php');
```

Is there a way to change the directory of /var/www/html/ to just /

Im sorry if my english is bad

Answer (score 1):

Try `require_once './connection.php';`
With `./` you will get the current directory

Comment: This works yes but I want to have the directory at / this is not possible? I have lots of files with / and I dont wish to open all php files and change them 1 by 1

Comment: No because / is root dir so it is like you want to include a file  that is is the same place than /var /etc

Comment: With a good text editor (like sublime text ) CTRL + shift +F. And replace requireonce/ by requireonce ./

Comment: How do some hosting companies do it? Whenever I go to the root I can go only as far as public_html however whenever I put a /connection.php it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your apache config points to `/var/www/html`.
You can change your apache configuration in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Then find and edit `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` to `DocumentRoot /var/www/` and save.  Don't forget to restart your apache service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```